# Why are these formulas not well-formed in syllogistic logic?

Tags: logic, syllogism

I'm studying formal logic, and I get stuck in the beginning.

I'm trying to do **easier translations** in **syllogistic logic**. I'm using Gensler book *"Introduction to Logic"*.

They say that this examples are **non-wffs** (well-formed formulas). And i don't get why:

> all A is not B

Why this are not wffs? **All logicians are not charming**. This is not valid?

> A is B

Again: **Logicians are charming**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "**A is B**" the explanation is simple.

Gensler's language has two types of "basic" formulae:

> (i) formulae expressing relation between sets ("general categoris"): "All logicians are charming", translated as "**all L is C**"
>
> (ii) formulae expressing the fact that an *individual* belongs to a set: "Gensler is a logician", translated as "**g is L**".

In this second case, **g** is the name of an *individual*; thus, we cannot quantify it with "all" or "some".

In the previous case, instead, **L** and **C** are names for sets and we have to quantify the first one in order to correctly express the relationship between them. If we say "Logicians are charming" (i.e. **L is C**) we have an ambiguous expression, because we do not know if we are asserting it of all or some Logicians.

---

I presume that he forbid the expression "**all A is not B**" as "ungrammatical" (*non-wff*) simply because it is already expressible as: "**no A is B**".